# OverscrollerIn android

Tags: android-widget

I have search a lot on android overscroller but did not get any appropriate matter
,so help me by providing good tutorial,

```
 I goes to Api Demo also but didnot get any thing that is undersatble
```

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Check API demo for 2.3.4 Version 10
 android-sdk-windows ->samples->version 10
```